# Java and nextInt() - what if user just hits enter?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm using a Scanner object to read in an integer from the user in a try/catch block. I catch wrong inputs (user entered a letter instead of a number etc). But if the user simply hits 'Enter' at the prompt, it simply enters a new line, and waits for the user to hit a key other than "Enter".

I can't see an easy way to capture this and let the user know they need to do something...?

Comment: Use `Scanner#nextLine` instead, check the resulting `String` to see if it's empty or not and either use another `Scanner` to parse the `String` or parse the `String` directly to an `int` with `Integer.parseInt` (just catch the exception)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know when the user enters a blank string (or you don't care and just want to deal with invalid input), I'd start by using `Scanner#nextLine` instead of `Scanner#nextInt` or `Scanner#hasNextInt`

By reading the whole line of text, you will also overcome the issue of the dangling new line character been left in the buffer, which can have adverse effects if you try and read from the `Scanner` again.

I'd then parse the `int` through a seperate workflow, for example...

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Integer intValue = null;
do {
    System.out.print("Please enter an int: ");
    String text = scanner.nextLine();
    try {
        intValue = Integer.parseInt(text);
    } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
        if (text.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("You must provide an input");
        } else {
            System.out.println(text + " is not a valid int value");
        }
    }
} while (intValue == null);

System.out.println(">> " + intValue);

System.out.print("This input should not be skipped: ");
String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println(">> " + nextLine);
```

Personally, I don't like using `try-catch` as a control mechanism and would instead make use of a second `Scanner` to do the parsing, but I appreciate that some people don't like that workflow either.

Also, I tried using `useDelimiter("\\R");`, but this did not solve the problem for me, in fact, it created more.

If I used `hasNextInt` or `nextInt`, I could press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice, before it was handled.  Subsequent inputs also seemed to double up (it would display two error messages) and didn't solve the issue of a dangling new line been left in the buffer. But, I'm probably no using it as expected.

So I ended up using the above workflow anyway.

I, personally, prefer to get the whole line of text from the user and then parse it as a seperate workflow, this reduces the potential for a lot of other issues associated with getting input from the user when using `Scanner` (looking at you dangling new lines)

Answer (score 1):

Simply configure the scanner for keyboard input. You do so as follows:

```java
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
s.useDelimiter("\\R"); // this fixes everything
```

Then, use any of the `.nextX()` methods to read whatever you want to read - except `nextLine()` which you simply do not use. ALL the next methods read entire lines (`.nextInt()` reads a line and parses it as an int, `.next()` just reads a line, etcetera).

### Why?

Out of the box, scanner is configured to treat 'any amount of whitespace' as the delimiter. This is not what you want or expect when dealing with keyboard input. As a consequence.. just hitting enter a bunch of times doesn't do anything - the delimiter is **any amount** of whitespace, and enter is.. whitespace. So just repeatedly hitting enter is just more delimiter; nothing happens.

By setting the delimiter to `\\R`, which is: Exactly one newline of any sort (different platforms have different newlines, `\\R` works for all of them), multiple enters would mean that the user is entering multiple delimiters, meaning, the `.nextX` methods return 'the things in between'. Blank string if need be.

This means calling `.nextInt()` when the user is repeatedly hitting enter, there *are* tokens being generated that the .next methods will return to you, but it's invalid when you ask `.nextInt()`. Now there is no difference whatsoever between a user just hitting enter and typing 'hello' and hitting enter. This makes it easy - just catch the appropriate exception (or use `.hasNextInt()` instead - whichever strategy you prefer). Works for both scenarios now.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, except, when I tested `nextInt`, it didn't provide a means to provide feedback to the user (although if you did press enter twice, it generated an error).  I'd, personally, use `nextLine`, but that's me

Comment: Yes, this was also one of the things I was trying to figure out - how do we tell the user they need to do something? If they enter a letter instead of a number, we can generate a nice error message, but it's not immediately obvious what's gone wrong if they just hit enter (either accidentally or on purpose). As one of my instructors noted once, "don't assume your user is stupid, but assume they'll sometimes (unknowingly) do stupid things with your program".

Comment: @Dragon-Ash  users are stupid .  I would start by using `nextLine`.  This will give you the opportunity to check it (to see if it's blank).  You can then parse it as a seperate step.  Alternatively, make use of `hasNextInt` to preemptively check that the input has a parsable `int` value.  The problem here is you still need to deal with the dangling new line